# Raspberry Pi Crontab issue

Tags: python, cron

I'm having trouble running my PHP script over crontab. The script is PHP with python that takes data from DHT22 and adds it to Mysql DataBase, then shows the result on HTML page.  When I do it manually works fine.

Here is the line I try to run every minute in crontab:

```
 * * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/cron/run.php
```

As I mentioned when I run the script in command line works fine but when I add it to crontab does nothing.

So far I have added Apache2 user to gpio with `sudo adduser www-data gpio` and also gave permissions to my python file with `sudo chmod +x /var/www/html/cron/python.py`

When I type: `ps -ef | grep cron` I get:

```
root 247 1 0 18:50 ? 00:00:00 /usr/sbin/cron -f
pi 1794 1119 0 19:48 pts/0  00:00:00 grep --color=auto cron
```

Any help is welcome :)

Comment: Excuse me but how is your PHP script connected to the Python script? Did you try to run your PHP script by yourself via terminal the same way as it configured for cron tab? Probably you have to make little changes to this: `* * * * * cd /var/www/html/cron && php run.php`

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution; don't add `sudo`... just `crontab -e`